# Regarding ArduinoBLE library compatibility

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno

I'm really new to Arduinos and was unable to find much info into this library, so looking for your advice!

I came across a repo that I wanted to try with an UNO. It uses a bluefruit to transmit data via BLE using their bluefruit library:
https://github.com/MagnusThome/RejsaRubberTrac

Coincidentally, there is the ArduinoBLE library, however it seems to only be compatible with certain boards? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLE

My question is, if I put a HM-10 onto my UNO REv3, would I be able to use the ArduinoBLE library? Or would you suggest I buy the bluefruit friend (https://www.adafruit.com/product/2479) or just change boards entirely?

Thank you!

Comment: it is not possible to use ArduinoBLE library with HM-10, without adding support for it to the library. the library only supports the nRF52 on Nano 33 BLE and ESP32 with nina-fw connected on UART

Comment: Thanks @Juraj I guess i'll have to buy the compatible board.